# Is Iterator method only for Set in Collection Framework?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, set

I was studying framework and I saw an example which is transferring from HashMap to Set like `Set set = map.entrySet();` then `Iterator it = set.iterator();` for using Iterator method for access each key set.

From that, I'm confused that is Iterator method only for Set in Collection framework?

Comment: Iterator isn't a method. It is a type (interface specifically) which holds methods which allows us to iterate over group of elements (like lists, queues, sets, etc.).

Comment: @Pshemo So, Is that allowed using Iterator with Map and List? ont only Set? Because the example is using Iterator after transfer from Map to Set for iterate over every each element in HashMap. Thanks for comment!

Comment: You can use `Iterator` with any `Collection`.

Comment: Not with Map since it isn't subtype of `Collection` (which is also subtype of `Iterable` which ensures that we can get `Iterator` from it). Map is "collection" of keys and values which create pairs, but over what should iterator traverse? Java designers probably wanted to make that decision to client-programmer and let him pick from `map.keySet()` `map.values()` or `map.entrySet()` and iterate over aspect of map they are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator<> is an interface, as is Collection<>.

An implementation of Collection is required to be iterable. It will provide an implementation of Iterator that is specialized to iterate over that collection type, and a method to return an instance of that iterator.

So, if I implement `class PileOfStuff implements Collection<Stuff>`, somewhere behind the scenes I'll have something like `class PileOfStuffIterator implements Iterator<Stuff>` and `PileOfStuff.iterator()` will return such an iterator.